# Vue Router - Failed to resolve async component after reloading page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using lazy load method to create an backend SPA.

Everything is working smoothing when I navigate the link.
Whenever I go to the **certain** page and reload the it, then Vue will prompt me some error messages.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

app.js:144 Error: Loading chunk 10 failed.
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete (app.js:98)

[vue-router] Failed to resolve async component default: Error: Loading chunk 10 failed.

[vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:

app.js:15254 Error: Loading chunk 10 failed.
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete
```

This is how my script looks like

```
const Home = (resolve) => require(['../components/Home.vue'], resolve)
const Category = (resolve) => require(['../components/Category.vue'], resolve)
const CategoryEdit = (resolve) => require(['../components/CategoryEdit.vue'], resolve)
const Register = (resolve) => require(['../components/Register.vue'], resolve)

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: __dirname,
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: Home },
        { path: '/home', component: Home },
        { path: '/category', component: Category },
        { path: '/category/edit/:id', component: CategoryEdit },
        { path: '/company/register', component: Register }
    ]
});

const nav = new Vue({ 
    router,
    components : {
        Home,
        Category,
        CategoryEdit,
        Register
    },
    ...
}).$mount('#app')
```

I recorded an GIF for better explanation.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXdpC.jpg

Comment: I'm having the same issue! Any solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What's your webpack configuration?

You probably need to set a public path in your output object:

```
output: {
  path:'/dist',
  filename: '[name].js',
  chunkFilename:'js/[id].[chunkhash].js',
  publicPath: '/',
},
```

Comment: Superb! That's what caused me headaches. Thanks

Comment: I wonder how this is done in 2023 where Vite is more and more commonly used.

Comment: I had the same issue, thanks. However, you need to double check that the value for public path set `/` in this case matches with the vue router base value. In this case, you should also set the router base to '/'

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question!
You should change

```
const Register = (resolve) => require(['../components/Register.vue'], resolve)
```

to

```
const Register = (resolve) => require(['../components/Register.vue'], m => resolve(m.default))
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue, and what resolved mine is just to rebuild `yarn` or `npm` (hope this helps others):

```
yarn run dev
# OR
yarn run watch
```